# How to find DeliveryagentID in different cities on same date

Tags: mysql

How to find DeliveryagentID in different cities on same date

Table

```
 DeliveryagentID, Date,    City,     Cnt_Delivery
'1001', '2021-03-21 00:00:00', 'Bangalore', '45'
'1002', '2022-03-21 00:00:00', 'Delhi',     '35'
'1002', '2023-03-21 00:00:00', 'Delhi',     '70'
'1002', '2024-03-21 00:00:00', 'Chennai',   '45'
'1003', '2021-03-21 00:00:00', 'Mumbai',     '45'
'1003', '2024-03-21 00:00:00', 'Mumbai',     '85'
'1003', '2024-03-21 00:00:00', 'Bangalore',   '50'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqGqp.png)

Output should be 1003 because its present in two cities on same date.

Did not get exeat output
#Q2 Write sql query to find AgentID at diffrent location on same date

```
select DeliveryagentID,
       Date,
       count(Date) as CountR 
from fraud 
group by Date,DeliveryagentID 
having CountR>1;
```

Comment: DeliveryagentID Date City Cnt_Delivery
1001 21/3/21 Bangalore 45
1002 22/3/21 Delhi 35
1002 23/3/21 Delhi 70
1003 21/3/21 Mumbai 45
1003 24/3/21 Mumbai 85
1002 24/3/21 Chennai 45
1003 24/3/21 Bangalore 50

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate by agent and date and then assert that two different cities are present:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT DeliveryagentID
FROM fraud
GROUP BY DeliveryagentID, Date
HAVING MIN(City) <> MAX(City);
```

The above query is fairly instance of where it makes sense to use `DISTINCT` along with `GROUP BY`.  A given agent might have multiple dates on which it was present in more than one city.  However, we only want to report each matching once, which the `DISTINCT` select handles.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, to find DeliveryagentID in different cities on same date,
you can use this query:

```
select DeliveryagentID,
       Date,
       count(distinct City) as CountR 
from fraud 
group by Date,DeliveryagentID 
having CountR>1;
```